# Visual Studio Code + WSL2 + Salesforce Extension Pack. Intellisense/code completion for Apex not working?

Tags: vs-code

After the long break I currently back to Salesforce ecosystem and I'm trying to setup my development environment - Visual Studio Code with DX features (Salesforce CLI, Scratch Orgs etc.) and Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL2). I installed and configured everything as supposed to be in Salesforce Docs but code completion not working in my VS Code. Without using WSL2 everything work as expected.

I had run out my ideas. It would be great if I will be able to take advantage of all Salesforce Extention Pack features.

Update. I noticed that Apex Language Server won't start.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use the WSL2? I've had success with Visual Studio Code and the Salesforce Extension Pack using the powershell terminal that is embedded in VSCode.

Comment: Reason is mainly my preference - bash terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve my problem. I configured WSL with OpenJDK1.8 and voilà:[image]